# Where is the dll file for the rlang package?

Tags: r, rlang

Perhaps an odd question but I've deleted the entire rlang folder in my R packages folder and am still seeing the same error message when I try and install the package via install.packages("rlang"):

```
library(rlang)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rlang', details:
  call: NULL
  error: The rlang package is not properly installed.
The DLL version does not correspond to the package version.
Please update rlang to the latest version.
```

I'm on Windows. I've read various threads on this topic and have followed the suggestions as far as I can - I'm using Windows on a work laptop and don't have access to the C:/ drive. My packages folder is on a drive I can access

Comment: I've got an `rlang.dll` in the `rlang/libs/x64` folder of the directory where my packages are saved, but there don't seem to be any other copies of it.  As you've deleted that, the problem might be a reference to it in the windows registry or a configuration file.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's where mine is/was

Comment: What happens when you start a new R session and do `install.packages("rlang")` - does that give an error message, or is it only when you try to load it?

Comment: When you use `install.packages` try and use the `lib` argument to specify where you would like to install that package - i.e. path to the drive that you have access. Similarly, when you load the library, use `lib.loc` argument to specify where to load from.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes, it seems to install ok, just when I try and load it. I can access RStudio only but I've ensured no packages are running and it's a brand new session before doing the install.

Comment: @JustinLandis  I am certain it's installing to my packages folder as I can see the files following the install. i've tried specifying the lib.loc argument but get the same error. It must be something in the files in the R installation itself.

Comment: Are you on an old version of R, perhaps?  Maybe the latest `rlang` is not compatible with it.  You could try looking on CRAN for an older version of `rlang` that runs with your version of R. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes I am on version 4.0.2, funnily enough I am trying exactly what you suggest now! A very frustrating problem

Comment: Although actually I can't do that as I need Rtools to build from source and my R version isn't compatible...

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was old enough to be a problem. A couple of other thoughts - can you load `rlang` if you run R from Rgui rather than RStudio? And can you check the C drive for any other copies of `rlang` that might be hiding there?

Comment: I get the same problem in Rgui. I can't access C drive but can browse it via the choose R installation dialogue and can't see rlang anywhere - checked the library folder. Cheers for the suggestions again

Comment: Can you access the `rlang` functions without loading the package - e.g. `rlang::is_double(3)`? And what about all of the tidyverse and other packages that use `rlang` - are they working?

Comment: trying to install and run tidyverse is actually my underlying issue - couldnt get it going because of this issue with rlang. And no, calling is_double I get the same DLL error

Comment: Almost out of ideas!  The `remove.packages` command "Removes installed packages/bundles and updates index information as necessary", so I wonder if it is worth trying that - thereby updating the "index" - before reinstalling.

Comment: no worries thanks for trying. if it was my home install i'd just start again but not possible in my org. bit of a nightmare